# Scriptlet in a JSP

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, scriptlet

I have two radio buttons. Information will pop out when one of the radio button is selected. How can I check if a radio button is selected using a scriptlet?

Comment: You use scriptlets? Kill it. Kill it with fire.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A scriptlet works only server side. It has no relation with the client side, so you have to check whether radio buttons are selected or not with JavaScript or [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) whichever client-side scripting language you are using.